# Receive location updates of OSMdroid's MyLocationNewOverlay

Tags: android, geolocation, maps, osmdroid, mylocationoverlay

I am using the `MyLocationNewOverlay` to show the user's current location. I already managed to place a marker, when the location is found for the first time (e.g. when the `runOnFirstFix()` function is called:

```
/* set start location */
mapController = mapView.getController();
mapController.setZoom(12);
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(mucLocation.latitude, mucLocation.longitude);
mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

/* MyLocation overlay */
mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(mapView);
mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
// mLocationOverlay.enableFollowLocation();
mLocationOverlay.setDrawAccuracyEnabled(true);

mLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.e("Location", "runOnFirstFix");
        mapController.animateTo(mLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
        Marker currentLocation = new Marker(mapView);
        currentLocation.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_location));
        currentLocation.setPosition(mLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
        currentLocation.setTitle("Hier bin ich");
        mapView.getOverlays().add(currentLocation);
    }
});
```

Now I would like to update the marker's location, whenever a location update is received. As far as I know this is not possible with `MyLocationOverlay`, but I hope that it will be possible with the new `MyLocationNewOverlay`. In the  [Documentation](http://osmdroid.azurewebsites.net/osmdroid-android-4.3-javadoc/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/mylocation/MyLocationNewOverlay.html) I saw that there is the `enableMyLocation()` which allows to receive location updates and the `enableFollowLocation()` which keeps centering the map at the current location. So it seems that the overlay is already able to provide regular location updates.

I know I could make use of Android's `LocationListener`, but it seems that this functionality is already inside `MyLocationNewOverlay` since its able to follow the location.

Does anyone know if there is a way to receive location updates through that overlay and could give an example about how to do that? I noticed the  [`MyLocationNewOverlay.onLocationChanged()`](http://osmdroid.azurewebsites.net/osmdroid-android-4.3-javadoc/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/mylocation/MyLocationNewOverlay.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location,%20org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.IMyLocationProvider)) function but couldn't figure out how to use it. Any ideas?

Comment: It should update the icon as long as enableMyLocation is turned on. Are you seeing a different behavior?

Comment: You mean the `onLocationChanged()` should update the icon that marks the current location? That functions sounds like a callback that is called when the location changed, but actually, it expects a location as parameter, so I don't understand what's the point of it.

Comment: @spy, okay, I just saw what you meant. Didn't get a GPS signal before. But now I saw that the man icon which shows up at my location. So I guess it's already implemented. Sometimes the person icon changes to a green arrow and then back to the person icon. Do you know why?

Comment: person = stationary, green arrow = in movement, showing the direction of moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer but hope it will help you.

As you noticed, there is `MyLocationNewOverlay.onLocationChanged()` method. In order to use it, you need to override it. Example below:

```java
MyLocationNewOverlay locationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(gpsMyLocationProvider, mapView) {
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location, IMyLocationProvider source) {
    super.onLocationChanger(location, source);

    // This is where you can use updated location
    useNewLocation(location);
  }
}
```

You may also receive location updates directly from `gpsMyLocationProvider`. Procedure is exactly the same, just override `onLocationChanged()` method, call `super` and do whatever you need with your data.

Answer (score 2):

In **Kotlin** it would be like this:

```
val locationOverlay =
            object : MyLocationNewOverlay(GpsMyLocationProvider(this), binding.map) {
                override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?, source: IMyLocationProvider?) {
                    super.onLocationChanged(location, source)
                    location?.let {
                        Log.i("MyCurrentSpeed", it.speed.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
locationOverlay.enableMyLocation()
binding.map.overlays.add(locationOverlay)
```