# How to get name of polygon or polyline if my location inthere ? (OSMDroid)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Im working with OSMDroid to make map offline in Android Studio.

this is my code to create Polygon :

```
polygon = new Polygon();
polygon.setPoints(list_polygon);
polygon.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#1D566E"));
polygon.setTitle(name_map);
polygon.getOutlinePaint().setColor(polygon.getFillPaint().getColor());
map.getOverlays().add(polygon);
```

this code is to create line :

```
line = new Polyline();
line.setPoints(list_line);
line.setGeodesic(true);
line.setColor(Color.parseColor("#E33E5A"));
line.getOutlinePaint().setStrokeWidth(30f);
line.setWidth(15f);
line.getPaint().setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
map.getOverlays().add(line);
```

and this code is to get my location :

```
myLocation = new MyLocationNewOverlay(map);
myLocation.enableFollowLocation();
myLocation.setDirectionArrow(icTruk, icTruk);
myLocation.enableMyLocation();
myLocation.setDrawAccuracyEnabled(true);
map.getOverlays().add(myLocation);
```

I have done to create polygon and polyline in osmdroid.
But now i want read that polygon or polyline if mylocation inthere ?
How to make it posible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to get the current location and then check if it is close to the Polyline.

```
MyLocationNewOverlay myLocation= new MyLocationNewOverlay(mapView) {
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location, IMyLocationProvider source) {
    super.onLocationChanger(location, source);

    // Turn the current location into a GeoPoint
    GeoPoint currentPoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude);

    // Set tolerance for isCloseTo 
    // Might need to play around with this value 
    // and see which fits best for your needs
    double tolerance = 5.0;

    // Check if location is close to Polyline
    if (line.isCloseTo(currentPoint, tolerance, map)) {
        // Do here what you want to do, 
        // when location is close to Polyline
    }
  }
}
```

Checking, if the location/GeoPoint is within a given polygon is a bit more work, since the only integrated method for that is based on MotionEvent rather than GeoPoint and only returns a correct value in a very specific scenario, see [this](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Polygon.html#contains-MotionEvent-) for reference. But there are some answers out there, which might be usable for your need, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36128812/9038475).

References:

- [Get the current location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73064938/9038475)
- [OSMDroid Geopoint class](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocs/osmdroid-android/debug/index.html?org/osmdroid/util/GeoPoint.html)
- [Android Location class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#getLatitude())
- [OSMDroid Polyline.isCloseTo](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Polyline.html#isCloseTo-org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint-double-org.osmdroid.views.MapView-)
- [OSMDroid Polygon.contains](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Polygon.html#contains-MotionEvent-)
- [One way to check if point is in a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36128812/9038475)